# Ansible: set_fact variable with loop

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I'm trying to use linux-system-roles/timesync with dynamic list of NTP servers whitch depends of group_vars or host_vars

As base I had:

In host_vars/server1.yml

```
serverip:
  - '1.1.1.1'
  - '2.2.2.2'
  - '3.3.3.3'
```

In host_vars/server2.yml

```
serverip:
  - '1.1.1.1'
  - '2.2.2.2'
  - '3.3.3.3'
```

In my role roles/set-ntp/tasks/main.yml:

```
- name: Legacy set_fact style
  set_fact:
    timesync_ntp_servers:
      - hostname: "{{ serverip[0] }}"
        iburst: yes
      - hostname: "{{ serverip[1] }}"
        iburst: yes
      - hostname: "{{ serverip[3] }}"
        iburst: yes

- debug:
  var: timesync_ntp_servers
- include_role:
    name: linux-system-roles.timesync
```

And my playbook.yml

```
- name: Configure servers
  hosts: server1,server2

  roles:
    - set-ntp
    - other-role1
    - other-role2
    - .....
```

And it works well because timesync_ntp_servers looks like:

```
TASK [set-ntp : debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "timesync_ntp_servers": [
        {
            "hostname": "1.1.1.1", 
            "iburst": true
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "2.2.2.2", 
            "iburst": true
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "3.3.3.3", 
            "iburst": true
        }
    ]
}
ok: [server2] => {
    "timesync_ntp_servers": [
        {
            "hostname": "1.1.1.1", 
            "iburst": true
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "2.2.2.2", 
            "iburst": true
        }, 
        {
            "hostname": "3.3.3.3", 
            "iburst": true
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem comes when I need to change NTP IP for servers to different count, as
In host_vars/server1.yml

```
serverip:
  - '1.1.1.1'
  - '2.2.2.2'
  - '3.3.3.3'
```

In host_vars/server2.yml

```
serverip:
  - '1.1.1.1'
  - '2.2.2.2'
  - '3.3.3.3'
  - '4.4.4.4'
```

My static variant is unusable now. I tried use loop with some googe pages and created this:

```
- set_fact:
    loop_item:
      - hostname: "{{ item }}"
        iburst: yes
  loop: "{{ serverip }}"
  register: loop_list

- name: Loop style
  set_fact:
    timesync_ntp_servers: "{{ loop_list.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.loop_item') | list }}"

- debug:
    var: timesync_ntp_servers
```

But variable "timesync_ntp_servers" now have additional degree of nesting with [] for each item pair:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "timesync_ntp_servers": [
        [
            {
                "hostname": "1.1.1.1", 
                "iburst": true
            }
        ], 
        [
            {
                "hostname": "2.2.2.2", 
                "iburst": true
            }
        ], 
        [
            {
                "hostname": "3.3.3.3", 
                "iburst": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

In that case linux-system-roles/timesync module dont work, it dont see variables. How to solve it, I have no ideas.

Comment: I assume that the set of NTP servers is small and not changing often. To reduce complexity would it be possible for you just to deploy a `template` like `ntp.conf.j2`? By using such approach in example I am able to maintain all `ntpd` config for more than 100 servers just with 2-3 tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop_item variable defines a list.
If you define it as a dict, I think it should solve your issue.

```
    loop_item:
      hostname: "{{ item }}"
      iburst: yes
```